# API для регистрации с использованием чистой архитектуры

Tags: python, fastapi, clean-architecture

Я начал делать приложение на fastapi. Пока что есть только функции регистрации и входа с jwt. Я хотел бы сразу начать использовать чистую архитектуру, но так как я новичок в этом, я не до конца понимаю какой слой для чего нужен. Можете на примере с регистрацией объяснить использование слоев чистой архитектуры?

Comment: Не понимаю, но делаю?..

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю ознакомиться с https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql, базовый шаблон проекта с использованием JWT от разработчика FastAPI.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос